# Installing the official Froyo for Nook Color on a rooted device

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, clockworkmod-recovery, root-access, nook-color

Last week I installed Honeycomb on my Nook Color, and today I found out that B&N released an official Froyo build for it, which I would like to try. I downloaded the update from [here](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/u/nookcolor-support-software-update/379002520/), and put the zip on my MicroSD already installed with ClockworkMod Recovery v3.0.1.0.

I started the Nook, formatted Data, System & Boot (in this order), and tried to install nookcolor_1_2_update.zip from the SD. The installer said "Can't open /sdcard/nookcolor_1_2_update.zip (bad)". I coped the file again to make sure it's not related to the unmount of the SD from my PC, and I also opened the file in WinRAR on my PC to verify that it's valid (it is).

What am I missing? I'm very new to Android and try to learn what I can from the web, so sorry if this is a super-newbie question...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the official 1.2 update will only install on top of an official firmware (1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0,) and only with the stock recovery, not ClockworkMod.

You will need to [revert](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=914690) your Nook Color to one of these "[stock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=919353)" firmware versions before trying to upgrade to 1.2.  Alternatively, there are [a few](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1050520) Clockwork Recovery-[friendly](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1051235) versions of the 1.2 upgrade that will not require going back to stock first.